# Can we add "OnStartups" as a migration suggestion?

Tags: feature-request, migration, suggestion

I would suggest to migrate [this question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/23068/need-guidance-for-finance-management-in-freelancing) to OnStartups, but when choosing "Off Topic", only "meta" appears as a migration suggestion option.

Can we have additional SE sites added to the list, OnStartup being the main migration target?

Comment: I was once schooled to "not migrate crap".  That questions isn't already a well thought out or well constructed question.  We are best to close it and suggest the poster try OnStartUps.

Comment: @MrChrister yes, that particular one may not be the best of questions ever...

Answer (score 3):

Migration paths for sites besides meta won't exist until the site leaves beta, according to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71901). Based on the [migration stats](https://money.stackexchange.com/tools/posts/migrated/away), it does look like a fair amount of questions have been migrated there over the last few years (although not as many recently). I don't know if enough questions have been migrated to warrant a separate migration path. I don't know what criteria are used to decide that.

That being said, if there is room for five sites (including meta.money.SE) in the list of migration paths once the site leaves beta, there's probably space for onstartups too. It certainly looks like it's in the top five sites that receive migrated questions.

Answer (score 3):

The most frequent destination for questions migrated *from* the site is actually Bitcoin SE (a total of 3) where 66% were rejected. OnStartups has received only one question from Personal Finance SE which (seems to have been) accepted. The second most frequent inbound route to Personal Finance SE is  actually Travel SE, a total of two, both accepted.

At this point, it's probably worth asking where you think *inbound* migrations would make sense as well. The heaviest comes from Quantitative Finance SE, a total of 6, where you've only rejected 16%. OnStartups hasn't sent any questions here to date.

The site just doesn't see a lot of migration activity, and that's *good*, but it makes establishing the initial routes a little difficult. OnStartups probably isn't going to be in your migration path - at least initially. There's really not much data to support adding any beyond meta, we'll keep a close eye on it once you get your design and your graduation status is completely official and add them as migration data (by mods) suggests sane paths.

Comment: I remember quite a few questions *closed* with comments suggesting to ask on OnStartups

Comment: Also, the link @JohnBenson posted suggests much more than 1 migration...

Comment: Right now as there are no direct migration paths, quite often the old questions are closed and manually posted on relevant sites. If we have a generic migration path "Migrate to other SE" and the a Moderator actually migrating would generate us the required data ... we can then build direct migration paths for these instead of Mod

Comment: @littleadv I'm going by the migration statistics (unfortunately moderator only). I'm not saying it's out of the question, there's just not enough data to say yes or no at this time.

Comment: @TimPost Out of curiousity, can you perhaps post a screenshot of those statistics? Are they referring to the last 90 days only (which is the time period for the [statistics that high-rep users can see](http://money.stackexchange.com/tools/posts/migrated/stats)), or something else? Those statistics only list one question, but they only include a short time period.

Comment: @littleadv Most of the time the OnStartups team didn't think they were a good fit, or good enough questions.